# How do you code a purge command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, purge

So I have been search far and wide over the internet, trying to find a possible way to make a purge command. Now I have found quite a lot of different ways to make one, but none of them either suited me in the way I wanted, or simply worked for me.
SO to start off, here is my code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"); // use discord.js

const BOT_TOKEN = "secret bot token :)" // bot's token
const PREFIX = "*" // bot's prefix

var eightball = [ // sets the answers to an eightball
    "yes!",
    "no...",
    "maybe?",
    "probably",
    "I don't think so.",
    "never!",
    "you can try...",
    "up to you!",
]

var bot = new Discord.Client(); // sets Discord.Client to bot

bot.on("ready", function() { // when the bot starts up, set its game to Use *help and tell the console "Booted up!"
    bot.user.setGame("Use *info") // sets the game the bot is playing
    console.log("Booted up!") // messages the console Booted up!
});

bot.on("message", function(message) { // when a message is sent
    if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return; // if the message is sent by a bot, ignore

    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return; // if the message doesn't contain PREFIX (*), then ignore

    var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" "); // removes the prefix from the message
    var command = args[0].toLowerCase(); // sets the command to lowercase (making it incase sensitive)
    var mutedrole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "muted");

    if (command == "help") { // creates a command *help
        var embedhelpmember = new Discord.RichEmbed() // sets a embed box to the variable embedhelpmember
            .setTitle("**List of Commands**\n") // sets the title to List of Commands
            .addField(" - help", "Displays this message (Correct usage: *help)") // sets the first field to explain the command *help
            .addField(" - info", "Tells info about myself :grin:") // sets the field information about the command *info
            .addField(" - ping", "Tests your ping (Correct usage: *ping)") // sets the second field to explain the command *ping
            .addField(" - cookie", "Sends a cookie to the desired player! :cookie: (Correct usage: *cookie @username)") // sets the third field to explain the command *cookie
            .addField(" - 8ball", "Answers to all of your questions! (Correct usage: *8ball [question])") // sets the field to the 8ball command
            .setColor(0xFFA500) // sets the color of the embed box to orange
            .setFooter("You need help, do you?") // sets the footer to "You need help, do you?"
        var embedhelpadmin = new Discord.RichEmbed() // sets a embed box to the var embedhelpadmin
            .setTitle("**List of Admin Commands**\n") // sets the title
            .addField(" - say", "Makes the bot say whatever you want (Correct usage: *say [message])")
            .addField(" - mute", "Mutes a desired member with a reason (Coorect usage: *mute @username [reason])") // sets a field
            .addField(" - unmute", "Unmutes a muted player (Correct usage: *unmute @username)")
            .addField(" - kick", "Kicks a desired member with a reason (Correct usage: *kick @username [reason])") //sets a field
            .setColor(0xFF0000) // sets a color
            .setFooter("Ooo, an admin!") // sets the footer
        message.channel.send(embedhelpmember); // sends the embed box "embedhelpmember" to the chatif
        if(message.member.roles.some(r=>["bot-admin"].includes(r.name)) ) return message.channel.send(embedhelpadmin); // if member is a botadmin, display this too
    }

    if (command == "info") { // creates the command *info
        message.channel.send("Hey! My name is cookie-bot and I'm here to assist you! You can do *help to see all of my commands! If you have any problems with the Minecraft/Discord server, you can contact an administrator! :smile:") // gives u info
    }

    if (command == "ping") { // creates a command *ping
        message.channel.send("Pong!"); // answers with "Pong!"
    }

    if (command == "cookie") { // creates the command cookie
        if (args[1]) message.channel.send(message.author.toString() + " has given " + args[1].toString() + " a cookie! :cookie:") // sends the message saying someone has given someone else a cookie if someone mentions someone else
        else message.channel.send("Who do you want to send a cookie to? :cookie: (Correct usage: *cookie @username)") // sends the error message if no-one is mentioned
    }

    if (command == "8ball") { // creates the command 8ball
        if (args[1] != null) message.reply(eightball[Math.floor(Math.random() * eightball.length).toString(16)]); // if args[1], post random answer
        else message.channel.send("Ummmm, what is your question? :rolling_eyes: (Correct usage: *8ball [question])"); // if not, error
    }

    if (command == "say") { // creates command say
        if (!message.member.roles.some(r=>["bot-admin"].includes(r.name)) ) return message.reply("Sorry, you do not have the permission to do this!");
        var sayMessage = message.content.substring(4)
        message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
        message.channel.send(sayMessage);
    }

    if(command === "purge") {
        let messagecount = parseInt(args[1]) || 1;

        var deletedMessages = -1;

        message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: Math.min(messagecount + 1, 100)}).then(messages => {
            messages.forEach(m => {
                if (m.author.id == bot.user.id) {
                    m.delete().catch(console.error);
                    deletedMessages++;
                }
            });
        }).then(() => {
                if (deletedMessages === -1) deletedMessages = 0;
                message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: Purged \`${deletedMessages}\` messages.`)
                    .then(m => m.delete(2000));
        }).catch(console.error);
    }

    if (command == "mute") { // creates the command mute
        if (!message.member.roles.some(r=>["bot-admin"].includes(r.name)) ) return message.reply("Sorry, you do not have the permission to do this!"); // if author has no perms
        var mutedmember = message.mentions.members.first(); // sets the mentioned user to the var kickedmember
        if (!mutedmember) return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server!") // if there is no kickedmmeber var
        if (mutedmember.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("I cannot mute this member!") // if memebr is an admin
        var mutereasondelete = 10 + mutedmember.user.id.length //sets the length of the kickreasondelete
        var mutereason = message.content.substring(mutereasondelete).split(" "); // deletes the first letters until it reaches the reason
        var mutereason = mutereason.join(" "); // joins the list kickreason into one line
        if (!mutereason) return message.reply("Please indicate a reason for the mute!") // if no reason
        mutedmember.addRole(mutedrole) //if reason, kick
            .catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't mute because of : ${error}`)); //if error, display error
        message.reply(`${mutedmember.user} has been muted by ${message.author} because: ${mutereason}`); // sends a message saying he was kicked
    }

    if (command == "unmute") { // creates the command unmute
        if (!message.member.roles.some(r=>["bot-admin"].includes(r.name)) ) return message.reply("Sorry, you do not have the permission to do this!"); // if author has no perms
        var unmutedmember = message.mentions.members.first(); // sets the mentioned user to the var kickedmember
        if (!unmutedmember) return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server!") // if there is no kickedmmeber var
        unmutedmember.removeRole(mutedrole) //if reason, kick
            .catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry ${message.author} I couldn't mute because of : ${error}`)); //if error, display error
        message.reply(`${unmutedmember.user} has been unmuted by ${message.author}!`); // sends a message saying he was kicked
    }

    if (command == "kick") { // creates the command kick
        if (!message.member.roles.some(r=>["bot-admin"].includes(r.name)) ) return message.reply("Sorry, you do not have the permission to do this!"); // if author has no perms
        var kickedmember = message.mentions.members.first(); // sets the mentioned user to the var kickedmember
        if (!kickedmember) return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server!") // if there is no kickedmmeber var
        if (!kickedmember.kickable) return message.reply("I cannot kick this member!") // if the member is unkickable
        var kickreasondelete = 10 + kickedmember.user.id.length //sets the length of the kickreasondelete
        var kickreason = message.content.substring(kickreasondelete).split(" "); // deletes the first letters until it reaches the reason
        var kickreason = kickreason.join(" "); // joins the list kickreason into one line
        if (!kickreason) return message.reply("Please indicate a reason for the kick!") // if no reason
        kickedmember.kick(kickreason) //if reason, kick
            .catch(error => message.reply(`Sorry @${message.author} I couldn't kick because of : ${error}`)); //if error, display error
        message.reply(`${kickedmember.user.username} has been kicked by ${message.author.username} because: ${kickreason}`); // sends a message saying he was kicked
    }

});

bot.login(BOT_TOKEN); // connects to the bot
```

It is the only file in my bot folder except the package.json, package-lock.json and all the node_modules.

What I'm trying to do is type in discord *purge [number of messages I want to purge] and get the bot to delete the amount of the messages I asked it to delete, PLUS the command I entered (for example, if I ask the bot to delete 5 messages, he deletes 6 including the *purge 5 message.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) (`bulkDelete()`) method for Discord.js.

It bulk deletes a message, just simply pass in a collection of message in the method and it will do the job for you.
(You can use `messages` property from channel, otherwise if you prefer promises, then try `fetchMessages()` method. )

Just make sure that the channel is not a voice channel, or a DM channel. And finally, your bot needs to have permission too.

You can get your own bot's permission for the guild using `message.guild.member(client).permissions`, or you can just directly use `message.guild.member(client).hasPermission(permission)`, which returns a boolean that determines if your bot have a desired permission.

(The method docs for `hasPermission()` is [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission))

Answer (score 0):

note sure if this is still relevant but this what i use in my bots

```
     if (!suffix) {
    var newamount = "2";
  } else {
    var amount = Number(suffix);
    var adding = 1;
    var newamount = amount + adding;
  }
  let messagecount = newamount.toString();
  msg.channel
    .fetchMessages({
      limit: messagecount
    })
    .then(messages => {
      msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
      // Logging the number of messages deleted on both the channel and console.
      msg.channel
        .send(
          "Deletion of messages successful. \n Total messages deleted including command: " +
            newamount
        )
        .then(message => message.delete(5000));
      console.log(
        "Deletion of messages successful. \n Total messages deleted including command: " +
          newamount
      );
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error while doing Bulk Delete");
      console.log(err);
    });
```

basic function is to specify number of messages to purge and it will delete that many plus the command used, the full example is [here](https://github.com/lbryio/lbry-wunderbot/blob/master/bot/modules/purge.js)