# How would I make a Purge Command that logs to a channel of what was purged

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm looking to create a command that purges the chat but also log what was purged in said chat to a mod-logs channel that only Mods/Admins and above can see.

I am looking for something similar to Dyno BOT's purge command but without the webapp side of things.

Also I'm doing my code like so:

```
if(command==="purge){
message.delete()// This deletes the command


// CODE GOES HERE
}else{ 
// This mentions the commanding person if they do not have the following permission MANAGE_MESSAGES
message.reply("Nice try, you do not have MANAGE_MESSAGES permission.")

   }
}
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563610/9304377

Comment: That does help, for the purging but not the logging unfortunately :(

Comment: Use channel.fetchMessages, then loop through each of the messages returned: `for const message of messages.values()`. For each message, use channel.send to send the message to whatever the log channel is, then message.delete() to delete each message.

Comment: Also, the Discord.js server is incredibly useful for any Discord.js questions. You always get instant responses compared to Stack Overflow: https://discordapp.com/invite/bRCvFy9

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option is to use channel.fetchMessages, and send each message before deletion.

This example might work:

```
async function purgeMessages(count, channel, logChannel) {
    const messages = await channel.fetchMessages({ limit: count }).catch(console.error);
    for (const message of messages.values()) {
        await logChannel.send(message.content).catch(console.error);
        await message.delete().catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

Note that this will not send attachments or embeds. If you want to send those as well, you will need to loop through `message.embeds` and `message.attachments`.

Another option might be to monitor [the messageDeleteBulk event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageDeleteBulk), and send the messages that were deleted using a similar method.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easily triggering rate limits if you start sending 100 messages as fast as you can to another channel?

Comment: Definitely would hit the rate limits, both sending the messages and deleting other ones.

Comment: @SjoerdDal @André It does not send 100 messages as fast as it can. `await` delays the next promise until the previous promise has successfully completed. This means everything happens sequentially, with only one operation occurring at any time. I have similar code for my bot, and it has not encountered any rate limits as of yet.

Comment: Although there may be other rate issues, most of the limits that I have encountered are due to too many requests at once. Although this code creates many requests, there will only be a single request at any time. Hopefully it works.

Comment: Will look at this later on tomorrow as I have been very busy with other commands.
Hopefully this works :D